# JQuery UI Slider Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've checked all of the questions on SO and I can't seem to find the answer. If I place integers directly into the fields then this works but I want to set the parameters dynamically when I set up my script

I'm running JQuery 1.11.1, JQuery UI stable (1.11.0) and touchpunch. I've debugged and the variables are all present and initialised when this is invoked. I've also tried wrapping in self-executing functions with the same results.

(The slide function can be disregarded)

This throws the exception

**EDIT** I've just noticed that if I click on the slider the exception is thrown but if I then press the right arrow key no exception is thrown and the amount is populated with the value property. I've pasted console output at the end of the question.

```
$("#slider").slider({
            value: parseInt(window.settings.principal.minimum),
            min: parseInt(window.settings.principal.minimum),
            max: parseInt(window.settings.principal.maximum),
            step: parseInt(window.settings.principal.increment),
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider").slider( "value"));
            }
        });
```

However this WILL work

```
$("#slider").slider({
            value: 500,
            min: 500,
            max: 10000,
            step: 500,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider").slider( "value"));
            }
        });
```

Console Output

```
jQuery("#slider").slider("value"); 
5000
jQuery("#slider").slider("min"); 
Error: no such method 'min' for slider widget instance
jQuery("#slider").slider("minimum"); 
Error: no such method 'minimum' for slider widget instance
jQuery("#slider").slider("max"); 
Error: no such method 'max' for slider widget instance
jQuery("#slider").slider("interval"); 
Error: no such method 'interval' for slider widget instance
jQuery("#slider").slider("step"); 
Error: no such method 'step' for slider widget instance
jQuery("#slider").slider("values"); 
[]
```

Comment: Give your variables (`window.settings.principal.*`) another look. I just copied your source code, replaced them with my own, and it worked.

Comment: Surely if they're defined at the moment the $("slider") function is called they are ok? Are you using the same library versions ?

Comment: Apologies the issue was that the max was lower than the initial value, they were integers and being parsed correctly. Would you like to post an answer or should I just delete the question?

Comment: I posted an answer that will hopefully be able to help people in the future, since the error it throws isn't descriptive at all and someone's bound to run into the same problem and find this through Google.

Comment: I got this error when I accidentally passed a function as my slider max, instead of an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your variables (`window.settings.principal.*`) another look. I just copied your source code, replaced them with my own, and it worked, so your code seems to be fine. Make sure that they're not only valid numbers, but that they make sense in context.

Comment: The issue turned out to be my maximum integer being lower than the initial value so unlike all of the other issues where the problem is providing non-integer variables, my problem was providing wrong integer variables :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. Just on a trial n error base, i've discovered that the problem lies within the parseInt() function. I've removed the function and just used the raw data :

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value: window.settings.principal.minimum,
    min: window.settings.principal.minimum,
    max: window.settings.principal.maximum,
    step: window.settings.principal.increment
});
```

It seems we're copying an old piece of snippet for the slider. I have no ideea what is wrong with parseInt() in this setup, as i'm not that technical, but i hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Please check minimum and maximum values, min value should be less than max value.

Please check below example for reference.

```
$( ".slider1"+blockid ).slider({
    range: "min",
    value:0,
    min: 100,
    max: 10000,
    step : 10000,
    animate:true,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui.value);
    },
    create: function(event,ui){
    }
});
```